# Simple eigenvalue of an edge-transitive k-regular graph

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G$ be an edge-transitive and $k$-regular graph and $\lambda$ be its simple eigenvalue.

Show that $\lambda = \pm k$.

Definitions:

$G$ is **edge-transitive** if for any two edges $e$ and $e'$, there exists an antomorphism of $G$ mapping $e$ to $e'$.

**Simple eigenvalue** of $G$ is an eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix $A(G)$ of $G$ with multiplicity 1.

Comment: What confuses me is the connection of the edge-transitivity and the spectrum of a graph.

Comment: Is your problem to prove that $\pm k$ is an eigenvalue or that it is simple?

Comment: We aim to prove that $\pm k$ are the only possible  simple eigenvalues.